# How can I add to the custom listview user control the tasks like editing the items columns groups?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

The reason for this control is to make the listview stop flickering when scrolling.
The flickering has stopped and it's working fine but the listview control don't have the same properties like the regular winforms listview.

In this screenshot the listview with the ListView Tasks window is the regular listview and the smaller rectangle the empty one is the custom control.

[image: ListView]

This is the custom control listview code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileSearcher
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListViewControl lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnf.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
            lvnf.Columns.Add("", 984, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListViewControl : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewControl()
            {
                //Activate double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
                // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the columns on my own and got the same view as the original list view control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileSearcher
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListView lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListView();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.HideSelection = false;
            lvnf.MultiSelect = false;

            //lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            //lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            //lvnf.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Path", 212, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Path", 90, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("Last modified", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnf.Columns.Add("", 984, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListView : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListView()
            {
                //Activate double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
                // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Working good without any flickers.